# Facebook API call against users with privacy control set

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm querying my friends and instead of returning 283, its returning 274 with a paging key. Could it be possible that 9 of my friends have a privacy set to not be included in the insights? Here is the code I am using:

```
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
print "<pre>";
print_r($friends);
print "</pre>";
```

Comment: It’s called “Opting out of the Platform” in FB privacy settings. If a user choses that, they can not use any apps any more themselves, nor are they “visible” in _any way_ to other apps.

Answer (score 0):

Base on your code it will `return` the list of your `facebook friends`. And of course it has a `page key` that has a limit of `5000`.

to double check the total `count` of your return callback you can check it here

[click here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/friends)

Comment: If the paging is set at 5000 than I am going to assume that 9 of my friends have a privacy control set to not be included when I call `/me/friends`

Comment: I'm not so sure.. maybe it's because of the privacy or maybe you are blocked on them.